# Почему не работает скрипт JS в html?

Tags: javascript, html

При нажатии button в тег audio.src должен пережаваться путь к файлу на пк (в данном случае указал рандомные буквы), но этого не происходит.

```
    <audio class="AudioPleer1" src="" controls></audio>
    <button onclick="document.querySelector('.AudioPleer1').src = ffg">Play</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял проблему, ссылка должна писаться в кавычках, то бишь в виде .src="ffa". А вообще, советую не использовать onclick. На мой взгляд, лучше написать так

```
const audio = document.querySelector('.AudioPleer1');
const playButton = document.querySelector('.button'); //добавил класс для кнопки

playButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    audio.src = "ffa";
});
```